# Running Scripts without Interruption from Amazon Workspace Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, amazon-web-services, python3, workspace

I am running a Windows 10 Desktop Amazon Workspace.  This is set to "always on".  There are python scripts that I wish to run there indefinitely.

However, the workspace will restart itself as and when Windows 10 Updates are scheduled to be downloaded.  This terminates all of the scripts and restarts the workspace with none of them running.

So far, I have:

Looked into whether it is possible to turn off these updates so as to avoid the restart interruptions.  It does not look like this is possible.  Is that correct?

Tried to use windows task scheduler to relaunch the scripts each time the Workspace reboots.  This has not worked either, despite following various tutorials on how to use the windows task scheduler to launch python scripts on startup.

Specficially, my question is how best can I run python scripts indefinitely on an Amazon Worskpace Windows 10, given that it needs to be this rather than a non-GUI platform?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For stopping Amazon WorkSpaces scheduled default maintenance for your WorkSpaces,
see the article
[WorkSpace Maintenance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/workspace-maintenance.html).

The above article describes how to disable Amazon maintenance mode or set it to Manual.

For disabling Windows Update, this is only possible for a limited time,
as follows:

- Open *Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update > Advanced options*.
- Under the "Pause updates" section, use the drop-down menu and select the
  number of days you want to defer quality updates (unfortunately only up to 30 days).
- Do the same for the two options under "Choose when updates are installed".

Comment: Thanks.  I already had the "defer feature updates" option checked in this advanced options section.  FYI - there was no "pause updates" section or "choose when updates are installed" section.  I think perhaps the approach of setting all the scripts to all run each time the "always on" workspace reboots is the best approach, but I am still struggling with getting this to work at the moment, despite working through the approach as described above with the windows task scheduler.